# How to import commons-io.jar jsp/java

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, apache-commons-fileupload

I am getting an exception:

```
Cannot find symbol: FileUploadException;
```

I have a piece of code which uses

```
FileUploadException
```

The library that needs importing is:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
```

The path to my project is :

```
D:\Projects\website
```

In the project folder I have each in its folder:

```
Tomcat, Derby, Website
```

I have copied:

```
commons-fileupload.jar and commons-io.jar
```

into both:

```
Tomcat/lib and Website/Web-INF/lib
```

**---------------I tried this--------------**

just importing the library on its own

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
```

adding the jars to the class path upon build:

```
javac -cp .;D:Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-fileupload.jar;D:\Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-io.jar com/otrocol/app/*.java
```

adding them to the Environment variables CLASSPATH

```
D:Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-fileupload.jar;D:\Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-io.jar
```

I also tried adding the jars where my .java files are as @Scot Ship suggested

**----mentions---**

*I am not using any IDE*

The code contains more unrecognized symbols, but I'm trying to solve one at a time

First time using apache, tomcat, jsp.. please be gentle

Comment: I would have expected `Website/WEB-INF/lib`. Just try an IDE once, NetBeans is simple and minimal.

Comment: This is the easy way out. I can import other packages like derby.jar, or servlet-api.jar and they work perfectly.. its' just this one that's gving me a headache. Also there is no guarantee that after spending ours configuring eclipse the way I want it it will even work.

Answer (score 1):

Vlad, the web container will automatically look for JARs inside

```
/WEB-INF/lib
```

even without any developer intervention. Take note that it's all caps WEB-INF. As long as your JAR is there, it will be in your web application's classpath.

Try to display this in one of your servlets or JSP:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

and you'll get a better view of what classes and JARs were actually loaded.

**Update:** After reviewing your question, it appears you're facing issues in compiling the files to begin with and you're doing it *outside* an IDE.

Take note that when you use -cp in javac like this:

```
javac -cp .;D:Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-fileupload.jar;D:\Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-io.jar com/otrocol/app/*.java
```

Whatever value you have set in the CLASSPATH environment variable becomes ignored.

Be absolutely sure that the class FileUploadException is indeed inside one of the JARs you're trying to import: you can view the JAR directly using an unarchiving tool.

Also, change the com/otrocol/app/*.java to com\otrocol\app*.java - you should be using your system delimiter (not that this may affect your problem).

Create a simple HelloWorld in the same location as the file you're compiling, add the SystemOut mentioned above, and compile it the same way you're doing for the concerned file.

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/faq.html#class-not-found. Probably you have the fileupload jar but you also need commons-io.jar in your classpath as well.

Comment: if you read the text of my question you will see I have also added commons-io to the path

Comment: I guess you should try putting the jars in the same directory as your .java file to start. javac in general assumes current directory as start of classpath. If that doesn't work, you may have corrupt .jar files or there is some other problem with the .jar files.

Comment: Just more info from <http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html>: The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

Comment: also In the text of the question above you will see my classpath override contains the .;    : javac -cp .;D:Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-fileupload.jar;D:\Projects\website\Tomcat\lib\commons-io.jar com/otrocol/app/*.java

Comment: maybe I'm a complete moron and using the wrong jars.. could you please provide me with the links to the correct ones please?

Comment: You should find both jars at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/